# Can i put flurry code in onCreate() and onDestroy()?

Tags: android, flurry

I am trying to use flurry for my android app. It says that i should put flurry code in onStart() and onStop() methods. I dont have these methods in my code. I have two activities and both use onCreate() and onDestroy() methods only. Can i put flurry code in that? Will there be any problem with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

onStart() and onStop() are methods that handle part of an activity lifecycle, so you can add them to your activities without any problem.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(...) {
    super.onCreate(...);
            ...
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, "your_key");
}

@Override
public void onStop()
{
   super.onStop();
   FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
}
```

Comment: Add them in your activity at the same level of the onCreate method, I have edited my answer.

Comment: @gwa- i tried this. but did not see any activity in flurry? do i need to wait for sometime?

Comment: that is just the initialization, then you have to follow their documentation for adding code and getting their offers. Sorry but it's too long to write in here. Hope I helped you to start!

Answer (score 3):

`onStart` and `onStop` are existing methods on an [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), just like `onCreate`. If you want to add functionality at these points of the [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle), you can override them just like you did for `onCreate`.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, "FLURRYKEY");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop()
    {
       FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
       super.onStop();
    }
}
```

`onCreate` and `onDestroy` are not an appropriate pair of methods to use for Flurry session tracking because `onDestroy` is not guaranteed to be called. See the documention on [`onDestroy`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29). You can end up with situations where the app gets killed by the system and Flurry will think the session is still going.

> There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so it should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around after the process goes away.